# Would you tell me what 'play off of' means in this context?

Tags: word-meaning, phrase-meaning, phrasal-verbs

> *Go pear shaped* (The plan isn't working / plan is going wrong)
>
> ... In all likelihood, this has nothing to do with the fruit, but
>   rather ***plays off of*** the expectation of something being round, but
>   instead having it be an odd shape.

Could I have your help in interpreting the phrasal verb? I looked it up in dictionaries. It has several meanings. I expect that means '*to react to or interact with, as in a drama*'. I'm not sure of whether I am right though.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Both "play on (something)" and "play off (something)" mean to use that thing as a starting point for some *variation*, often humorous or interesting.  Many jokes are a *play on words*, meaning that they manipulate some expected phrase in a clever way.  An English pun:

> In the winter my dog wears his coat, but in the summer he wears his coat and pants.

I could say this is a *play on/off* of "coat and pants", common articles of clothing.  An animal's fur, collectively, is referred to as his "coat", or "coat of fur".  Meanwhile "pants" as a noun means *trousers*, but as a verb means *to breath heavily*.  Dogs *pant* when they are tired or overheated.

So in summer, an overheated dog will wear his *coat* (of fur) and *pant* (breath heavily).

There is little difference between "play on" and "play off".  The nuance is mostly directional, and which you choose to say depends on context and individual preference.